# Is there a way in JavaFX to have textfields appear depending on past input in a seperate text field?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm somewhat new to using JavaFX and was wondering if there was a built in way to have textfields appear depending if the user enters an integer value. For example, a textfield will be asking how many employees are still on duty, and then depending on the integer value entered, the appropriate number of textfields will appear to enter employee names.

Comment: Yes, of course. Where specifically are you stuck? Create and post a [mre] showing the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?
Not production ready but I hope enough to get you started.
Notes after the code.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Spinner;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFlds extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();

        Spinner<Integer> spinner = new Spinner<>(0, 100, 0);
        Label label = new Label("How many");
        HBox hBox = new HBox(10, label, spinner);
        root.setTop(hBox);

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vBox);
        spinner.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable,
                                Number oldValue,
                                Number newValue) {
                if (newValue.intValue() > oldValue.intValue()) {
                    vBox.getChildren().add(new TextField());
                }
                else if (newValue.intValue() < oldValue.intValue()) {
                    ObservableList<Node> children = vBox.getChildren();
                    int size = children.size();
                    children.remove(size - 1);
                }
            }
        });
        root.setCenter(scrollPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

- The `Spinner` value determines how many `TextField`s to display.
- All the `TextField`s are placed in a `VBox` and the `VBox` is placed in a `ScrollPane`.
- Whenever the `Spinner` value is increased, another `TextField` is added to the `VBox` and whenever the `Spinner` value is decreased, the last `TextField` is removed from the `VBox`. Note that the `Spinner` can only be increased, or decreased, by one.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about a built-in way, but it sounds like this can be achieved using a simple loop.

I would create a function that accepts an integer as a parameter(N), then in the function validate the value of N as needed, and in a for-loop generate the N number of textfields.

sudo code:

```
public void generate_N_fields(int N){
   //Do some validation first to ensure N is a valid value
    
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
       // generate a textfield here
    }
}
```

So the input to the function, the parameter N, will be the numeric value that you read from the initial textfield (number of customers)